# Eclipse Helios ignores breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-jdt, helios

Eclipse is driving me nuts right now. It's probably something trivial but I just don't get it. Whenever I like to add a breakpoint, the regular icons are crossed out in the editor and breakpoints view.

As you might have guessed, this isn't strictly a graphical problem ;) The breakpoints are simply ignored while debugging. The breakpoint's properties aren't helpful either.

Any hint is very well appreciated!

EDIT:

- I've tested different JDKs without success.
- I've **successfully** debugged projects in another workspace

Okay, so it's not about the JDK or the installed plugins. Seems to be workspace related. Anything I could try?

Comment: I stopped using Helios after wasting one day trying to get things working (mostly plugins). I'll just wait a bit more, at least things are working with Galileo. Not very constructive, but that's my experience.

Comment: @Jim Thanks, I've updated the URL. @Pascal I did a short test and everything I needed worked fine, breakpoints included. Going back to Galileo would require some extra work I'd love to avoid.

Comment: I experienced a level of frustration with this type of thing that bordered on the insane. I eventually ditched eclipse for another Java IDE. It's taking time to get used to it, but I'm not looking back, I'm far more productive now without eclipse's quirks killing my inner child.

Comment: Helios JEE works fine for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems you have the *Skip All Breakpoints* option enabled in the *Breakpoints* view.

Comment: +1; that's what's happening.  As evidenced by the line through each breakpoint icon.  Also reachable using the `Run` menu.

Comment: This is where a hover message explaining what the icon really _means_ could be useful.

Comment: +1 thanks a lot! looks like i've just discovered another handy feature ;) @Thorbjørn definitely! that's what i was looking at first.

Comment: @Thorbjørn I've just submitted a bug report ;) https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319086

Comment: This saved my day.. lost almost a whole day looking for a solution why my breakpoints where skipped.

Comment: +1 Why, why, why, why, why can this thing still happen in Eclipse 3.7? I just spent an hour trying to find out what the \*\*\*\* was happening. No warnings, no tooltips, nothing. Just one tiny little button in the wrong state...